# How do I center content in a Panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, alignment

I have a panel, inside which I am trying to center the controls. But apparently, panels don't like padding when they are docked to the edge of a control. Here is the current code for my panel:

```
buttonPanel = new Panel();
buttonPanel.Width = 300;
buttonPanel.Height = 50;
buttonPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
buttonPanel.Padding = new Padding((this.ClientSize.Width - buttonPanel.Width) / 2, 0,
                                 (this.ClientSize.Width - buttonPanel.Width) / 2, 0);
buttonPanel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
this.Controls.Add(buttonPanel);
```

I have a single button placed inside the panel. What I would expect with the above code, is that the control is placed nicely to the left of a 300 wide "rectangle" centered in the panel. But the button is placed on the very left, as if the padding is ignored:

[image]

How can I center a collection of buttons to the center of my form?

Comment: Padding is observed by containers that perform automatic layout.  Like FlowLayoutPanel and TableLayoutPanel.  Not Panel, it is simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Design Time Approach**

At design time, put your button in your container and select your button. Then, use **Center Horizontally** and **Center Vertically** from **Layout** toolbar to put your button in center of panel. After, go to your buttons properties and remove every anchor from Anchor property.

**Coding Approach**

```
Panel panel = new Panel();
panel.Size = new Size(300, 100);
panel.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;

Button button = new Button();
button.Size = new Size(70, 25);
button.Location = new Point((panel.Width - button.Width) / 2, (panel.Height - button.Height) / 2);
button.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;

panel.Controls.Add(button);
this.Controls.Add(panel);
```

Comment: I don't use the designer, I code it all from scratch

Comment: @user3189142 It's all the same if you're coding or not. Having anchors removed helps you to keep your controls at wherever they are so they're always aligned with the parent size.

Comment: Well, that `button.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;` solved the problem of the button not moving :D thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to align the button inside the panel by setting the button's position not the panel's padding:

```
button1.Left = (int)(panel1.Width * 0.5f - button1.Width * 0.5f);
button1.Top = (int)(panel1.Height * 0.5f - button1.Height * 0.5f);
```

or

```
button1.Location = new Point()
{
    X = panel1.Width / 2 - button1.Width / 2,
    Y = panel1.Height / 2 - button1.Height / 2
};
```

the result is the same.

If you override the `OnResize` method the button will stay centered also when you change the size of the form:

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Location = new Point()
    {
        X = panel1.Width / 2 - button1.Width / 2,
        Y = panel1.Height / 2 - button1.Height / 2
    };
    base.OnResize(e);
}
```

Comment: It half works lol. It puts it in the right spot, but remains in that spot even when I resize the form. Is there a way to fix that too?

Comment: I've added another example.

Comment: It still doesn't move. It just stays in the one spot and appears to move off the form when I resize it. If I make it bigger it comes back again. You did fix the position thought, so +1 for that.

Comment: I tested it myself before posting the answer so it definitely works. If it won't work for you there must be some other reason or properties that you've set to non default values.